# Run asynchronous functions with different return types in parallel

Tags: rust, async-await, parallel-processing, rust-tokio

I have 2 different asynchronous functions called inside a `process` function.

```rust
use actix_web::Result;

pub struct A {
    // Some fields below.
}

pub struct B {
    // Some fields below.
}

pub async fn process() -> Result<ApiResult> { 
    let connection_string = env::var("DATABASE_URL").expect("env DATABASE_URL is not set");
    let pool: sqlx::Pool<sqlx::Postgres> = PgPool::connect(&connection_string)
        .await
        .expect("Problem connecting with the database");
    let a = func_a(&pool).await?;
    let b = func_b(&pool).await?;

    // Does more stuff below using `a`, and `b`. 
}

pub async fn func_a(pool: &PgPool) -> Result<A> {
    // Does some stuff below.
}

pub async fn func_b(pool: &PgPool) -> Result<B> {
    // Does some stuff below.
}
```

How can I run `func_a` and `func_b` in parallel?

---

While going through different posts and somewhat similar questions, I tried [`tokio::task::JoinSet` example](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/task/struct.JoinSet.html#examples) like below with no luck so far.

```rust
pub trait CommonTrait {}

pub struct A {
    // Some fields below.
}

pub struct B {
    // Some fields below.
}

impl CommonTrait for A {}
impl CommonTrait for B {}

pub async fn process() -> Result<ApiResult> { 
    let connection_string = env::var("DATABASE_URL").expect("env DATABASE_URL is not set");
    let pool: sqlx::Pool<sqlx::Postgres> = PgPool::connect(&connection_string)
        .await
        .expect("Problem connecting with the database");
    let mut tasks = JoinSet::new();

    tasks.spawn(async { Box::new(func_a(&pool)) });
    tasks.spawn(async { Box::new(func_b(&pool)) });

    // Does more stuff below using `a`, and `b`. 
}
```

But the Rust compile throws with:

```
expected `{async block@src/service.rs:34:17: 34:69}` to be a future that resolves to `Box<impl Future<Output = Result<A, Error>>>`, 
but it resolves to `Box<impl Future<Output = Result<B, Error>>>`
expected struct `tokio::task::JoinHandle<Box<impl std::future::Future<Output = Result<A, actix_web::Error>>>>`
   found struct `tokio::task::JoinHandle<Box<impl std::future::Future<Output = Result<B, actix_web::Error>>>>`
distinct uses of `impl Trait` result in different opaque types
```

Comment: _In parallel_, or _concurrently_?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Sorry for the confusion. I meant in parallel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to complete you `JoinSet` example to retrieve the values of `a` and `b`, and the problem should become clearer: all the results of the `JoinSet`'s tasks are retrieved via the *same* method [`JoinSet::join_next`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/task/struct.JoinSet.html#method.join_next), so they must have the same type.

To run both functions concurrently and in parallel, you can use [`tokio::task::spawn`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/task/fn.spawn.html), or [`tokio::task::spawn_blocking`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/task/fn.spawn_blocking.html) if your functions make blocking calls. This would look like this:

```rust
let task_a = tokio::task::spawn(func_a());
let task_b = tokio::task::spawn(func_b());
// at this point, both tasks are running in parallel
let a = task_a.await?;
let b = task_b.await?;
// at this point, both tasks have produced their result
process_both(a, b);
```

If instead, `a` and `b` need to be processed *independently*,
and you don't want to wait for one in order to process the other,
then you should include the processing in the tasks:

```rust
let task_a = tokio::task::spawn(async {
    let a = func_a().await;
    process_a(a).await
});
let task_b = tokio::task::spawn(async {
    let b = func_b().await;
    process_b(b).await
});
let a_processed = task_a.await?;
let b_processed = task_b.await?;
```

Comment: I personally like to see a way that would work for `n` number of parallel functions. But I guess that might not be possible. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

In my previous answer, I didn't notice the fact that A and B implement a common trait. Assuming this trait is [object safe](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/traits.html#object-safety), you could indeed use a JoinSet. But this means that you could only process the produced elements via the common trait.

```rust
use tokio::task::JoinSet;


pub struct A { /* ... */ }
pub struct B { /* ... */ }
pub trait CommonTrait: Send {}
impl CommonTrait for A {}
impl CommonTrait for B {}

pub async fn func_a() -> Result<A, ()> {
    // Does some stuff below.
    todo!()
}

pub async fn func_b() -> Result<B, ()> {
    // Does some stuff below.
    todo!()
}

pub async fn process() -> Result<(), ()> { 
    let mut tasks: JoinSet<Result<Box<dyn CommonTrait>, ()>> = JoinSet::new();
        
    tasks.spawn(async { 
        func_a().await.map(|a| -> Box<dyn CommonTrait> { Box::new(a) })
    });
    tasks.spawn(async { 
        func_b().await.map(|b| -> Box<dyn CommonTrait> { Box::new(b) })
    });
    
    while let Some(_x) = tasks.join_next().await {
        // do something with x, that only relies on CommonTrait
    }
    Ok(())
}
```